# How to prevent form validation on cancel dialog?

Tags: validation, primefaces

I have a dialog which is closed with the following button:

```
<p:commandButton
onclick="propertyEditDialog.hide(),propertyEditDialog.loaded=false" 
value="#{i18n['button.cancel']}" ajax="true"/>
```

There is no action, only client side javascript that simply hides the dialog. However, I've seen in the logs, that the form is validated on cancel. I've set the `ajax="true"` to prevent form validation, but it not helped anyway.

What is the right way to close the dialog in PrimeFaces without validating the form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ajax="true"` is the default behaviour of `p:commandButton`!

The right way would be to exclude the inputs of beeing processed. With the attribut `process="@this"` in the commandButton, only the button should be processed.

But if you dont want to fire some action and do not want to submit the form, maybe you better use a push-button (instead of a submit-button) by adding the attribute `type="button"` to your commandButton.

Answer (score 7):

You can use attribute `immediate="true"` to avoid validation.